# C++ if Statement coding error

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I am trying to get this if statement to work but every time I try to build it, I get this error:

```
no matching constructor for initialization of std::string'(aka'basic_string<char>')
```

I am using Xcode on mac if this helps any and if you can explain why i need to do this so i can avoid the problem next time

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "               Menu" << endl << endl;
    cout << "   press 1 to play the word game." << endl << endl;
    cout << "  press 2 too see the answer to 2+5." << endl << endl;

    string UserInput;
    cin >> UserInput;


    std::string y('1');
    if (UserInput == y) {

    }
    cout << "Enter A Word";
}
```

Comment: And why write `std` if you are using a namespace?

Comment: -1: Please, update your post. The Q has nothing to do with the `if` statement.

Comment: @loler: A better question is why do you have `using namespace std;` Stop it please. prefix stuff in the standard namespace with `std::`

Comment: This `std::string y('1');` does not compile. So the question really becomes what should this mean.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` has default constructor and constructor overloads that takes `const char*` but there is no constructor overload that takes `char` So either make it `y("1")` or do `std::string y(1, '1')`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
std::string y("1");
```

Single quotes indicate a character and not a string, and you can't construct a std::string from a character.

Comment: Single quotes in C and C++ mean *character* and not *string*. It's only by coincidence that this works for `'y'`.